# Set cursor position to 0 when edittext gains focus

Tags: android, android-edittext

When the user selects an `EditText`, I would like the cursor position to start at 0. The purpose of this `EditText` is to make it easier to enter in a time in `HH` format.

Here is my attempted focus change listener:

```
txtStartHH.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                txtStartHH.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
```

Below is my text watcher code, which may or may not be relevant:

```
txtStartHH.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        boolean formatting;
        int mStart;
        int mEnd;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            this.mStart = -1;
            mStart = start + count;
            mEnd = Math.min(mStart + count, s.length());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!formatting)
            {
                formatting = true;

                if (s.toString().length() == 3)
                {
                    if (mStart >= 0)
                    {
                        if (s.toString().substring(mStart - 1, mStart).matches("[0-2]+") && mStart == 1)
                        {
                            if (Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)) > 1 
                                    && Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(mEnd)) > 3)
                            {
                                s.replace(mEnd, mEnd + 1, "3");
                                s.replace(1, 2, "");
                            }
                            else
                                s.replace(mStart, mEnd, "");
                        }
                        else if (s.toString().substring(mStart, mEnd).matches("[0-9]+") && mStart == 2)
                        {
                            if (Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(1)) > 3
                                    && Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)) > 1)
                            {
                                s.replace(0, 1, "1");
                                s.replace(2, 3, "");
                            }
                            else                                
                                s.replace(mStart, mEnd, "");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // remove the character that has just been entered (i.e, cancels the insertion)
                            s.replace(mStart - 1, mStart, "");
                        }
                    }

                    if (mStart > 2)
                    {
                        s.replace(mStart - 1, mStart, "");
                    }
                }
                else
                {                   
                    if (mStart == mEnd && s.toString().length() < 2)
                    {
                        if (mStart == 1)
                        {
                            // user has just backspaced the second char
                            s.insert(mStart, "0");
                            mStart--;
                            txtStartHH.setSelection(mStart);
                        }
                        if (mStart == 0)
                        {
                            // user has just backspaced the first char
                            s.insert(mStart, "0");
                            mStart--;
                            txtStartHH.setSelection(mStart);
                        }
                    }
                }

                formatting = false;

                if (mStart > 1 && !jumpingTimes)
                {
                    txtStartMM.requestFocus();
                    txtStartMM.setSelection(0);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

However, when the `EditText` is gaining focus, the cursor is appearing in the position that the `EditText` was pressed, instead of at the start. What is wrong here - is there a different method I can use that works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing when the `OnFocusChangeListener` gets triggered (which is before android moved the cursor to the pressed location) set your cursor when user pulls the finger up the screen.

You can achieve this using [`setOnTouchListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) method and checking for the action [`ACTION_UP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP). 
Example:

```
txtStartHH.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (hasFocus) {
                txtStartHH.setSelection(0, 0);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just highlights all the text in the field for some reason :(

Comment: That's weird. Try changing the range to a from-to standard - `setSelection(0, 0)`.

Comment: Same effect. My `TextWatcher` modifies the text in the `afterTextChanged` method. If changing the selection counts as `Text Changed`, then this is probably the cause of the problem. I have no idea how to get around the issue though.

Comment: Can you post the code where you edit the text? You could set the pointer to the beginning after editing the text, but htat might be more often that you like.